# How is the HDL simulation timeout specified when using OpenCPI?

Tags: simulation, hdl

My simulation fails to stop until an inbuilt timeout is reached. The default is 3600 seconds. How do I set this to a different time period?

The openCPI version is 2.4.3.

Any suggestions?

This is my first use of OpenCPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default timeout for tests using the Timeout attribute in the Tests element of your test XML like below:

```
<Tests UseHdlFileIO="true" Timeout="30">
    <Case>
        <!-- Inputs and Outputs in here -->
    </Case>
</Tests>
```

The timeout is defined in seconds. More information can be found in section 13.3.5 of the [OpenCPI Component Development Guide](https://opencpi.gitlab.io/releases/v2.4.3/docs/OpenCPI_Component_Development_Guide.pdf)